# Problems with mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Following is the code snippet i am using to connect to a db.
Its getting connected, but unable to execute even the simplest of select queries on the DB.

```
 <html>
  <head>
   <title>Testing Script Nonce</title>
  </head>
  <body>

   <FORM NAME ="form1" METHOD ="POST" ACTION = "testing.php">

   <INPUT TYPE = "TEXT" VALUE ="" NAME = "comment">
   <INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "Submit1" VALUE = "Enter Comment">

   </FORM>


   <?php 
      $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","******") or die(mysql_error());

      if(!$con)
    {
        echo " not connected";
    }


   //$comments = $_POST['comment'];
   //print ($comments);

    $db_selected = mysql_select_db('test', $con);

  if($db_selected)
    {
        echo " selected db properly";
    }



     $query = "SELECT * FROM data";

     $result = mysql_query($con,$query);
     $num=mysql_numrows($result);
     print ($num);

        ?>

   </body>
   </html>
```

It does not print the number of records present in the table 'data' and just does not do anything and keeps showing "selected db properly"  when i press submit.

mysqli_* is not working when i tried.

Any help is much apreciated, i am a beginner in php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `mysql_query();` function takes `query`first, then `connection`. like:

> `mysql_query(query,connection)`

Now, Change:

`$result = mysql_query($con,$query);`

to:

`$result = mysql_query($query, $con);`

Comment: @JATMON Such a noob mistake